# Is it possible to use auto-filter or find on a dictionary?

Tags: vba, excel

so I have a userform with comboBox serving as a dynamic-search box.

The data needed to be searched is located in another workbook (1200+ rows). To avoid constant opening and closing of that data-workbook, I load it all into dictionary during form initialization.

Now my question is: is it possible to quickly filter out dictionary data (and update combobox), as user is typing or do I need to change my approach?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is the code I have so far:

```
Option Explicit
Private emplDict As Object
'all other constants and functions are declared in a separate module named "code"
Private Sub btnClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub comboSearch_Change()
    Me.comboSearch.DropDown
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim xlWS As Worksheet
    Dim xlWB As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lstRw As Long
    Dim item As Variant

    Application.Run "code.xlHelper", False ' turn off screen updating, alerts, events

    Set emplDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set xlWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=SUB_PLANNING & EMPLOYEE_LIST)
    Set xlWS = xlWB.Sheets("namen_werknemers")

    With xlWS
        lstRw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lstRw, 1))
    End With

    For Each item In rng
        If Not emplDict.exists(item.Value) Then
            emplDict.Add item.Text, item.Offset(0, 1).Text
        End If
    Next

    xlWB.Close False

    Set xlWS = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing

    Application.Run "code.xlHelper", True
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Set emplDict = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any built in `Dictionary` object methods to filter it, so I'd manually do it. But please clarify the following: 1) _"as user is typing "_: where is the user supposed to type in? 2) _"(and update combobox)"_: what combobox is to be updated with what data?

Comment: user3598756 i meant functionality similar to what google search engine uses. As user is typing letters, suggestions appear. It'd all happen in a combobox. User types in query, combobox's drop down menu opens, showing the results found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The Key is to use the Dictionary's Keys.

Use the VBA Filter method to return an array of filtered Keys.

[image]

```
Private EEDict As Object

Private Sub cboEEList_Change()
    Dim Keys
    Keys = EEDict.Keys
    cboEEList.List = Filter(Keys, cboEEList.Text, True, vbTextCompare)
    cboEEList.DropDown

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim arData
    Dim x As Long

    Set EEDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    arData = Worksheets("Employees").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value2

    For x = 2 To UBound(arData)
        EEDict(arData(x, 1)) = arData(x, 2)
    Next

    cboEEList.List = EEDict.Keys
End Sub
```

---

I got the sample data from: [Fusion Tables - Employees.csv](https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?dsrcid=986724)

Comment: Good call, I didn't think you could use wildcards, so didn't think this was possible, but on further reading it has a filter for entries beginning with as a default http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_filter.asp

Comment: wow! amazing. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, Thomas

Comment: I'm glad that I could help.  Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: Hi @ThomasInzina! One question, where should I put your code in order to get the same results as in the image? It is not in a Module right? I tried it and also in a UserForm but I am getting only errors :/ Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, but a little messy would be a recordset, something like this, you'd need to add the excel ranges to it, where I've cobbled some values in.

```
Option Explicit

Private rs As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

Set rfiltered = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Filter = "Value like '" & Chr(KeyAscii) & "*'"

If Not rs.EOF Then
    Range("e1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = "E1:E10"
End If

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim fieldsArray(1) As Variant
Dim values(1) As Variant

rs.Fields.Append "Key", adVarChar, 5
rs.Fields.Append "Value", adVarChar, 5

fieldsArray(0) = "Key"
fieldsArray(1) = "Value"

values(0) = 4
values(1) = "as"

rs.Open
rs.AddNew fieldsArray, values
rs.Update

End Sub
```