# VBA: TextBox and ListBox

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, listbox

On my `UserForm` I have a `TextBox` where is write down my Serial Numbers, something like 421012.
Below it I have a ListBox with options like "Tools, Bench, Wheel"

What I'm attemting to do:

After I type my Serial that I just typed in, I click on one of the options in the `ListBox` and it should put a value behind my Serial.

Something like this: 421012 + "selecting Tools" =421012**15**

the "Bench" would get an result of 421012**45**

My code so far:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With ListBox1
.AddItem "Tools"
.AddItem "Bench"
.AddItem "Wheel"
End With
End Sub
```

Somehow I have to tell VBA that Tools equals 15 or Bench equals 45 etc.etc.

Comment: [Possibly relevant](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/140995/23788)

Answer (score 1):

Add a second column and then reference that when you're doing your concatenation of the value.  "42012" & me.listbox.column(1) should return the value of whatever is selected

```
with listbox
    .columncount = 2
    .additem
    .list(1,0) = "Tools"
    .list(1,1) = 15
    .list(2,0) = "Bench"
    .list(2,1) = 45
    .list(3,0) = "Wheel"
    .list(3,1) = 75
end with
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest this.  I'd personally set the column width of the "values" column to 0 though.

Comment: Keep getting Run time Error 381

Comment: I think the answer by @Comintern is much cleaner.  Didn't know about scripting dictionaries.  Very cool.

Answer (score 1):

I use this much more frequently with objects than with intrinsic types, but another option is to store a Dictionary containing lookups keyed on your ListBox items:

```
'Module level variable
Private SerialLookup As Scripting.Dictionary

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set SerialLookup = New Scripting.Dictionary
    With SerialLookup
        .Add "Tools", "15"
        .Add "Bench", "45"
        .Add "Wheel", "42"
    End With

    ListBox1.List = SerialLookup.Keys()
End Sub
```

Then you can retrieve whatever value you need by using it as an index into the Dictionary, i.e.:

```
TextBox1.Value = "421012" & SerialLookup.Item(ListBox1.Value)
```

Comment: @ThomasInzina - How do I always manage to forget that... Edited.

Comment: One of my coolest answers involved using dictionary keys: [Is it possible to use autofilter or find on a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162841/is-it-ppossible-to-use-autofilter-or-find-on-a-dictionary/39177064#39177064)