# Combobox with extended function

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a combobox which has search field and able to index the items in it.

For example if I press b, it will immediately suggest all items starting with letter b.

Is this possible in vba? If yes, can you please tell me how?
-- And an extra question, can I do this not using a form? --

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-Complete with only text and not numbers ComboBox Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572688/auto-complete-with-only-text-and-not-numbers-combobox-excel-vba)

Comment: I show have to do this using a Dictionary in my answer to this question: [is it possible to use autofilter or find on a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162841/is-it-ppossible-to-use-autofilter-or-find-on-a-dictionary/39177064#39177064)