# How to autocomplete a line with data suggestion?

Tags: vba, excel

**Context:**
In my company, some assistants fill out an Excel table, which is a users list (First Names, Last name, ID number). After, I use this list with a PowerShell script. But very often the users list is not correctly completed. For example, assistants forget to input ID number... .
So i would like help assitants to fill this Excel with data suggestions/autocomplete.

**Technical:**
 In the "Data" sheet, I have all data possible (First Names, Last name, ID number).
With the "Name Manager" I created:

- `d_FirstName` to select the first cell
- `c_FirstName` to select all column,
- `l_FirstName` to apply function: `=OFSSET(d_FirstName;0;0;COUNTA(c_FirstName)-1;1)`

In "Form" sheet, I created drop-down list with function: `=IF(A1<>"";OFSSET(d_FirstName;MATCH(A1&"*";l_FirstName;0)-1;;SUMPRODUCT((MID(l_FirstName;1;LEN(A1))=TEXT(A1;"0"))*1));l_FirstName)`
So, when the user types a letter, the drop down list "suggest" a correct FirstName.

**Question:**
How to adapt the last query, to complete a **line** with First Name and Last name and ID number corresponding  if user type only First Name ? 
For example: 
If user select a **First Name** in drop down list, Excel complete the lign with Last name and ID number corresponding .
If user select a **ID number** in drop down list, Excel complete the lign with Last name and First Name corresponding.

In second time, how to show dropdown list automatically when user type one letter ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean line, like in row, instead of lign?

Comment: In my example I used Employee Id  for the login.  You could easily change it to first name.  I would use the employee's ID because it is unique but if you want to use the names you are going to have to concatenate the first and last names and possible add middle initials or number to identify employees with the same first and last name.

Comment: In my answer to [is it possible to use autofilter or find on a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162841/is-it-ppossible-to-use-autofilter-or-find-on-a-dictionary/39177064#39177064) I show you how to filter a list using a Dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the combobox's properties and change event.  The combobox will take a 1 or 2 dimensional named range or a formula that returns a range as it's RowSource.  Here I have the text column set to the 3rd column.

[image]

[image]

---

```
Private Sub cboEmpID_Change()
    With cboEmpID
        If Not IsNull(.Value) Then
            lblEmployee.Caption = .List(.ListIndex, 1) & ", " & .List(.ListIndex, 0)
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ColumnWidths As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ColumnWidths = .Columns(1).Width & ";" & .Columns(2).Width & ";" & .Columns(3).Width
    End With

    With cboEmpID
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .ColumnWidths = ColumnWidths
        .TextColumn = 3
        .ListWidth = Range("Sheet1!A:C").Width
        .RowSource = "OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,3)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok i will try to implement your code. If you have a xlsm file to test your code, I am interested. In the comboBox, it's possible to search LastName OR FirstName OR ID  ? (and not just ID)

Comment: I made you a test stub: [Download Login.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nq871b1tuziqy5e/LogIn.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: Thank tou very much, I analysed some possibility and i think your proposal is the best. I customize your code for my needs. For example i adding a 'Add' button to write the selected item value on A5 cell, but i some errors :) If you want to help me your are welcome [Download my Excel Macro](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00907355953776521655)

Comment: Add button works !!! [Version 3](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=27515653259148981415). Next step: how to write on next line when user click on "Add" several times ?

Comment: Thank you again :) [Final Version](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07811796189854232288) I understood your code, i will continue to improve code (clear selected combobox value when user click on "Add"; Check duplicate entry; Improve visibility on combobox list; ...) Thank you for your help ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need making a cascading dependent Excel drop down list.[See](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/30/dependent-cascading-dropdown-lists-excel/)