# search engine using textbox and combobox

Tags: vba, excel

i have a userform which use textbox and combobox as a search engine. combobox will have the header for some field in excel table, and user will enter search value in textbox. then it will display the data in the listbox

example
combobox values are "Client", "Commune","Year".lets say i choose "Client" and enter faa in the textbox then click on the search button and it will display all data about faa in the listbox. or if i choose "Year" and enter 1998, it will display all data on the year 1988 in the listbox

the problem is my search button does not work, i have tried a few option but keep on getting error. below is example of my code in search button

```
    `Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim sat, s As Long
    Dim deg1, deg2 As String

    If TextBox7.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a value", vbExclamation
    TextBox7.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If ComboBox3.Value = "" Or ComboBox3.Value = "-" Then
    MsgBox "Choose a filter field", vbExclamation
    ComboBox3.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If


    deg2 = TextBox7.Value
    Select Case ComboBox3.Value
    Case "Commune"
    For sat = 2 To Cells(65536, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    Set deg1 = Cells(sat, "a")
    If UCase(deg1) Like UCase(deg2) & "*" Then
    ListBox1.AddItem
    ListBox1.List(s, 0) = Cells(sat, "D")
    ListBox1.List(s, 1) = Cells(sat, "E")
    ListBox1.List(s, 2) = Cells(sat, "F")
    ListBox1.List(s, 3) = Cells(sat, "G")
    ListBox1.List(s, 4) = Cells(sat, "H")
    ListBox1.List(s, 5) = Cells(sat, "I")
    ListBox1.List(s, 6) = Cells(sat, "J")
    ListBox1.List(s, 7) = Cells(sat, "K")
    s = s + 1
    End If: Next

    Case "Client"
    For sat = 2 To Cells(65536, "b").End(xlUp).Row
    Set deg1 = Cells(sat, "b")
    If UCase(deg1) Like UCase(deg2) & "*" Then
    ListBox1.AddItem
    ListBox1.List(s, 0) = Cells(sat, "D")
    ListBox1.List(s, 1) = Cells(sat, "E")
    ListBox1.List(s, 2) = Cells(sat, "F")
    ListBox1.List(s, 3) = Cells(sat, "G")
    ListBox1.List(s, 4) = Cells(sat, "H")
    ListBox1.List(s, 5) = Cells(sat, "I")
    ListBox1.List(s, 6) = Cells(sat, "J")
    ListBox1.List(s, 7) = Cells(sat, "K")
    s = s + 1
    End If: Next

    Case "Year"
    For sat = 2 To Cells(65536, "d").End(xlUp).Row
    Set deg1 = Cells(sat, "d")
    If UCase(deg1) Like UCase(deg2) & "*" Then
    ListBox1.AddItem
    ListBox1.List(s, 0) = Cells(sat, "D")
    ListBox1.List(s, 1) = Cells(sat, "E")
    ListBox1.List(s, 2) = Cells(sat, "F")
    ListBox1.List(s, 3) = Cells(sat, "G")
    ListBox1.List(s, 4) = Cells(sat, "H")
    ListBox1.List(s, 5) = Cells(sat, "I")
    ListBox1.List(s, 6) = Cells(sat, "J")
    ListBox1.List(s, 7) = Cells(sat, "K")
    s = s + 1
    End If: Next

   End Select
   End Sub`
```

Comment: The VBA  built in function Filter can filter a one dimensional array based on wildcards and keywords.  I have a cool example in my answer to [is it possible to use autofilter or find on a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162841/is-it-ppossible-to-use-autofilter-or-find-on-a-dictionary/39177064#39177064), I show how to filter the Keys (the Keys are a 1D array) of a Dictionary.

Comment: It seems you can do all of this using a table for your data and use auto filter

Comment: What error do you get and what line Is throwing it?

Comment: hai, it does not give any error but the button just wont work. data is not filtered and display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it's a matter of your *active* `worksheet` at the moment of the *query* being not the one you'd expect

so use fully qualified (up to `worksheet` object at least) range references

furthermore be aware VBA declaration statements *implicitly* assume a `Variant` type for any not *explicitly* declared variable, therefore;

`Dim deg1, deg2 As String`

would actually declare `deg2` as of `String` type but `deg1` as a Variant

this shouldn't have anything to do with your problem since after such a statement as :

```
Set deg1 = Cells(sat, "a")
```

`deg1` would be instantiated as of `Variant/Range` type and therefore `Value` would still be assumed as its default `property` and  `If UCase(deg1) Like UCase(deg2) & "*" Then` would work as if you had declared `deg1` as of `Range` type

but it'd be cleaner and clearer to declare:

```
Dim deg1 As Range, deg2 As String
```

or 
    Dim deg1 As String, deg2 As String

but in this latter case you'd have to change all:

```
Set deg1 = Cells(sat,...)
```

to

```
deg1 = Cells(sat, ...)
```

Finally you want to avoid repeating bunches of code lines that differs for tiny details and either adopt a more modular approach (with helper `Sub`s or `Function`s) or at least have that code repeated only once

all what above is reflected in the following refactoring of your code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim s As Long
    Dim deg1 As String, deg2 As String
    Dim colIndex As String
    Dim cell As Range

    With Me
        If .TextBox7.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please enter a value", vbExclamation
            .TextBox7.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If .ComboBox3.Value = "" Or .ComboBox3.Value = "-" Then
            MsgBox "Choose a filter field", vbExclamation
            .ComboBox3.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        End If

        deg2 = .TextBox7.Value
        Select Case ComboBox3.Value
            Case "Commune"
                colIndex = "A"
            Case "Client"
                colIndex = "B"
            Case "Year"
                colIndex = "D"
        End Select
    End With

    If colIndex <> "" Then
        With Worksheets("MyDataWorksheetName") '<--| reference your "data" worksheet (change "MyDataWorksheetName" to your actual "data" sheet name
            With .Range(.Cells(1, colIndex), .Cells(.Rows.count, colIndex).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column 'colIndex' cells from row 1 down to last not empty row
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=UCase(deg2) & "*" '<--| filter its 1st column (i.e. the only 'columnIdex' column) with 'UCase(deg2) & "*"'
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell filtered other than header
                    For Each cell In .Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--|loop through filtered cells in 1st column (i.e. column "K")
                        Me.ListBox1.AddItem
                        Me.ListBox1.list(s, 0) = Cells(cell.row, "D")
                        Me.ListBox1.list(s, 1) = Cells(cell.row, "E")
                        Me.ListBox1.list(s, 2) = Cells(cell.row, "F")
                        Me.ListBox1.list(s, 3) = Cells(cell.row, "G")
                        Me.ListBox1.list(s, 4) = Cells(cell.row, "H")
                        Me.ListBox1.list(s, 5) = Cells(cell.row, "I")
                        Me.ListBox1.list(s, 6) = Cells(cell.row, "J")
                        Me.ListBox1.list(s, 7) = Cells(cell.row, "K")
                        s = s + 1
                     Next cell
                End If
            End With
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: hai, apparently i tried this code on my worksheet but i gives out error 70, permission denied on line  Me.ListBox1.AddItem. i tried google the solution but nothing seems to work

Comment: did you set your ListBox1 columnscount property to 2?

Comment: i set my column count to 27 since i have 27 column field

Comment: You must have your `ListBox1` `Rowsource` property set: remove the range address from the Properties Window and it'll work

Comment: im sorry maybe i cant catch what you said but it still doest work

Comment: Select your ListBox1, open the properties windows, find the one named RowSource and clear it's value

Comment: @blxck, did you get through it?

Comment: and unfortunately, some of my data went missing everytime i click the search button.

Comment: 1) _"doesn't work"_ means what? 2) Is the "error 70" (or any other error) gone by now? 3) _"some of my data went missing everytime i click the search button"_ : my code doesn't delete any cell, while it just filters them so I guess you (or some error) stopped the macro before it reached `.AutoFilterMode = False` statement and show all data back: in this case just click "Filter" button under "DATA" tab

Comment: i still get  error 70, permission denied on line Me.ListBox1.AddItem

Comment: if you cleared ListBox1 `RowSource` property from Properties window and you still get that error then I guess you have that property set in your code. Check it out for some statement like `ListBox1.RowSource="...` and comment it

Comment: @blxck, did you get through it?

Comment: i cleared rowsource property and i dont have listbox1.rowsource statement in my code.. the error is gone but i still dont get the search result.

Comment: sorry for confusion, but i have got the solution to my problem. thank you for helping me and thank you for your time. happy to know you :)