# Combobox with list find function additem vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, find

Im trying to do a Combobox on VBA Excel that add items depending on the return of find function that look's if what i wrote exist in my worksheet and show the liste of all words that start with what i wrote. 
To be more clear, i want to create a kind of speed search box.

Here my userForm :http://hpics.li/e1e8123

And here my code
http://hpics.li/3a8c45a
Any idea?

Thank's

Comment: If you want it to be fast the [find solution isn't the fastest](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/). Other option that isn't on the link is to use a Dictionary Object

Comment: My answer to [is it ppossible to use autofilter or find on a dictionary?] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162841/is-it-ppossible-to-use-autofilter-or-find-on-a-dictionary) does just that.

Comment: Thank's for your answers.
I update the link of the code's screenshot. 
@danieltakeshi Now i know that "match" is the fastest one but i don't have time to look and try it.

Comment: @ThomasInzina That's what i'm looking for. Thank's

Comment: Awesome!! It's always makes me feel good when I recycle :).